# Average symbol for showing a math variable is the outcome of an average

Tags: math-mode

What is the best way to show that a variable is the outcome of an average, assuming that I am talking about reflectance value in spectral interval between two wavelenghts:

```
$$ Averaged\, Value = \frac{1}{\lambda_{f} -\lambda_{i}} \cdot \int_{\lambda_{i}}^{\lambda_{f}} \lambda d\lambda
$$
```

[image]

```
$$
\overline{R} = \frac{1}{\lambda_{f} -\lambda_{i}} \cdot \int_{\lambda_{i}}^{\lambda_{f}} \lambda d\lambda
$$
```

[image]

Comment: never use math italic for words the font is designed to make it _not_ look like a word but a product of variables. `\text{Averaged Value}` not `Averaged\, Value `

Comment: two comments, neither relevant to purpose of question: better to use `\[...\]` rather than `$$` ([Why is `\[ … \]` preferable to `$$`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503)), and use `\mathit{Averaged Value}` because these are words, not a string of variables (a basic principle regarding words vs. variables).

Comment: In math, it better to use a symbol instead of two words. For average it is better to use the `\bar` not the `\overline`: \bar{R} https://i.stack.imgur.com/2z6Nl.png

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I start from the assumption that readers can read, so there's no point in stating twice what you're talking about. If you don't need the quantity later, just state the value, otherwise define a symbol for it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

The averaged value of reflectance in the spectral interval between two wavelengths is
\[
\frac{1}{\lambda_{f} -\lambda_{i}} \int_{\lambda_{i}}^{\lambda_{f}} \lambda\, d\lambda
\]

The averaged value $\overline{R}$ of reflectance $R$ in the spectral
interval between two wavelengths is
\[
\overline{R}=
\frac{1}{\lambda_{f} -\lambda_{i}} \int_{\lambda_{i}}^{\lambda_{f}} \lambda\, d\lambda
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For the average of p(t) over T, I would propose:

```
$$P = {\left.\overline{p(t)}\right|_0^T}$$
```

in preference of

```
$$P = \frac{1}{T}\int_0^T p(t)\ \d t.$$
```

The reason being that the integration sign is intimidating for people without a mathematical background.  See:

[image: comparison]

Comment: This is already covered by question and other answer(s).

Comment: @Zarko my solution simplifies the notation.

Comment: Your notation is TeX specific. In LaTeX  is correct `\[` ... `\]` or `\begin{equation*}` ... `\end{equation*}` or ..., So, sorry I don't see anything what is simplified.

Comment: The first equation indicates average with limits.